# How can I count distinct rows in another table going through multiple relationships?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a series of relationship between tables and I would like to create a **measure** in the "person" table that gives for a "Person" the number of different skill he used in work_session during a given year (let's say 2020).

here's a quick relational schema :
[image: schema]

How can I achieve that ?

Comment: You should create a new table that return all the data you want, then perform the calculation.

Comment: If you have proper relation between tables, a measure can solve your issue. Can you show your sample data from those 4 tables and then show what is your expected output from those sample data.

Comment: @mkRabbani I already want to make a measure. And what information would you need in sample data ? I believe you don't need anything else than what I already gave. If I'm reluctant to give sample data it's because  it is confidential :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the dax formula i used :

```
measure =
var act = CALCULATETABLE(
    DISTINCT('WORK_SKILL_ASSOCIATION'[SKILL_ID]), 
    YEAR('WORK_SESSION'[DATE]) >= 2020
)
RETURN COUNTROWS(act)
```